# iOS 7, check for update in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, push-notification

I'm working on my first iOS app and I need the app to verify after every 4 hours if there is a new data in the data base. If the response is yes, I want the app to create notification for the user and I want this to work in the background. For that I did some research, I found that, to check for new update and push notification we can use the multitasking api introduced in iOS 7 (background fetch, remote notification or background transfer service) but that does that mean we have to do work in the side server? For me, I want to do all the work in local, I mean the app send request to check for new update and create notification for the user and all that, work in the background. Any help please.

thank you.

Comment: Simply use background fetch method and in that method you could make a call for new data and create UILocalNotification which you will push on to user but disadvantage is that there is no specified time limit after which background fetch method is been called. Also you can't provide a fixed time limit to it. That background method could get called in few mins or few hours or days.

Comment: not really true since when you opt-in to background refresh you hint at the OS how/when to call it. I agree it can not be exactly set

Comment: Just with a hint to OS we can't create a app or product and wait for response or reply back from OS. Also thank you for your agreement .Really appreciated !!!

Answer (score 4):

with background fetch => all can be done on client side
you can check for an update and if there is on schedule a local notification

e.g.

1. opt in to background refresh in the plist.

   ```
   UIBackgroundModes = fetch
   ```
2. tell os when to launch you

   ```
   [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:4*60*60];
   ```
3. do anything you want when the IOS starts your app:

   ```
   //make api call
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                      queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                              NSData *data,
                                              NSError *connectionError) {
                               BOOL hasUpdate =  ...check the response...
                                   if(hasUpdate) {
                                           UILocalNotification *theNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                                           theNotification.alertBody = @"test"
                                           theNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

                                           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:theNotification];
                                   }
                              }
                           }];
   ```

Note:
""If you kill an app from the multitasking UI, the system will never automatically launch the app again. The logic here is that, if the user has killed your app, they probably want it to stay dead.""

see
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler`
and
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler`

Comment: thank you @Daij-Djan for your answer, please one last question, if the user kill the app, the background fetch will still work?